# How to forcefully inline the function in GCC version 4.6.3?

Tags: linux, gcc, inline, gnu

How to forcefully inline the function in GCC version 4.6.3?

I have tried all the below different commands to forcefully inline the function with GCC compiler. But no option seems working.

```
inline __attribute__((always_inline))
__attribute__((always_inline))
__inline__
__inline__ __attribute__((always_inline))
__attribute__((flatten))
```

What might have going wrong? Is there any way to check what's the optimization level set?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a GCC function attribute to set the optimization level:

```
__attribute__((gnu_inline, always_inline, , optimize(3)))
static void myfunc(void) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Even the above solution is not working. My gcc version is 4.4.7. What would be the other options to force inlining in gcc?